# simple jquery based datagrid

Tags: jquery

Can anybody suggest a nice and clean simple jquery based datagrid, i don't need bulky features that comes with flexigrid or jqgrid. just need a paging and column sorter and of course with ajax support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)
- [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid)
- [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)
- [Ingrid](http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/) and the [ingrid-google-code-site](http://code.google.com/p/jq-ingrid/updates/list)

Comment: ingrid is nice, and it has ajax support now, im trying it.

Answer (score 1):

[Extjs](http://www.extjs.com/) has a nice data grid, supports AJAX, and can work with jQuery. It might be considered "bulky", though.

Comment: too bulky, and having 2 different frameworks on 1 page is evil, lol